# How to use shared volume for multiple docker services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-volume

I am trying to use a shared external volume (state) for four services composed by docker. However, I am noticing that my state is not being stored for some reason. Below is my docker-compose.yml file.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  plus:
    build: ./addition
    image: plus_image
    volumes:
      - state:/state
  minus:
    build: ./subtraction
    image: minus_image
    volumes:
      - state:/state
  multiply:
    build: ./multiplication
    image: multiply_image
    volumes:
      - state:/state
  divide:
    build: ./division
    image: divide_image
    volumes:
      - state:/state

volumes:
  state:
    external: true
```

Below is the code for the addition application

```py
import sys, os

STATE_DIR = './state'

def add(op1, op2):
    result = op1 + op2
    return result

def getOperand():
    value = 0
    if os.path.exists(STATE_DIR + '/value'):
        print('exits')
        with open(STATE_DIR + '/value', 'r') as f:
            if f.readable():
                value = int(f.read().strip())
    print(value)
    return value

def save(value):
    print('saivng')
    if(not os.path.exists(STATE_DIR)):
        os.makedirs(STATE_DIR)
    with open(STATE_DIR + '/value', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numArgs = len(sys.argv)
    if(numArgs == 2):
        try:
            op1 = getOperand()
            op2 = int(sys.argv[1])
        except:
            print('Invalid input!')
            exit(1)
    else:
        print('Usage: python3 <operation>.py op1')
        exit(1)
    result = add(op1,op2)
    save(result)
    print(result)
```

Running

```bash
docker run plus_image 10
```

should output 10 for the first run.

Running the same command again, it must print 20 (10 from input + 10 from the volume)

Directory structure for this project

```bash
.
 |-division
 | |-division.py
 | |-Dockerfile
 |-subtraction
 | |-Dockerfile
 | |-subtraction.py
 |-multiplication
 | |-Dockerfile
 | |-multiplication.py
 |-addition
 | |-Dockerfile
 | |-addition.py
 |-docker-compose.yml
```

If you have come across such an issue, kindly help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `STATE_DIR = './state'` Why is there a dot in front? What is the current working directory?

Comment: My apologies. I added the directory structure to the question description. The application is expecting a './state' directory in the working directory of the container

Comment: I don't care about the structure. What is the current working directory for the python script when it is executed? Please post the ouptut of `print(os.getcwd())`. Is the current working directory root directory? Because `./` is _relative_ to currnet working directory.

Comment: Yes it is the root directory.

Comment: To clarify common confusion, Is it `/root` or root directory? `Running the same command again` What is the exact output of the command? What is the content of `Dockerfile`? How was state volume created?

Comment: Okay state volume as you can see in the compose file, is externally created. The WORKDIR is app in the dockerfile. Exact output for every run is 10. It is not adding the previous value which I am trying to store in the volume.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
docker-compose run plus 10
```

by command

```
docker run plus_image 10
```

you run container from image plus_image and you don't use compose file

by

```
docker-compose run plus
```

you run service plus (witch use image plus_image) from your compose file

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path instead of relative path:

```
STATE_DIR = '/state'
```

Otherwise, if you want use relative path, verify the `WORKDIR` used in the Dockerfile, then mount the shared volume in the proper folder